# How do I make a single script work on multiple tabs in the same sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am fairly new to this, I have a script that will update the time stamp when any cell in the row is edited, however I cannot get it to work for multiple sheets. It works for `Sheet 1` but no matter what I do I cannot get it to also work for `Sheet 2` as well, I thought I could copy and paste it below and and change the sheet name but it hasn't worked

Here is the script

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet 1") //
  {
    var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Timestamp") + 1;
    if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && e.range.columnStart > 1)
    {
      sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "MM-dd-yyyy"));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const selected = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];
  if (~selected.indexOf(sheet.getName())) {
    var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Timestamp") + 1;
    if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && e.range.columnStart > 1) {
      sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "MM-dd-yyyy"));
    }
  }
}
```